# How to read messages for web sphere mq and spring

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to find some tutorials on how to use the jms template and spring to read messages from a queue. Essentially i want to let the user say show me the last x number of messages on the queue

All i can find is examples of how to send messages using jms and spring. Is it possible to read the last x messages from a queue (webspehere) using jms / spring and if it is would someone be able to post a code example or point me to a website that demonstrates such functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> show me the last x number of messages on the queue

That's not how you do it.  MQ is NOT a database.  You read a message, process it then read the next message process it, etc...

Comment: I used a queue inspector in the end so it didn't remove it from the queue